# Connecting to Web Socket

Tags: c#, websocket

I am new to C# sockets.
I am trying to connect to Web Socket, but I am neither getting connected message nor error message and no Exception.

What I need to do to connect with web socket? How can I trace whether it is trying to connect to socket?

My Code:

```
private WebSocket client;
const string host = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443";

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    client = new WebSocket(host);
    client.OnOpen += (ss, ee) =>
    MessageBox.Show("Concceted");

    client.OnError += (SetStyle, ee) =>
    MessageBox.Show("error");

    client.Connect();
}
```

Comment: *"How can I trace what it is trying to connect to socket?"* Have you tried WireShark?

Comment: Use wireshark or fiddler which you can download for free from the web.  the server must be started at the host before connection.  I would also try from cmd.exe >Ping stream.binance.com to make sure you have a connection.  You may not be getting to your code so make sure the button click is working.  You can also check for errors in the windows event viewer.

Comment: Which WebSocket class is this? Can you provide the fully qualified name or doucmentation of WebSocket class used here.The one here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket(v=vs.110).aspx
is abstract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you use `WebSocketSharp`. The following console test program tries to connect to the same url from your question:

```
using System;
using WebSocketSharp;

namespace Example
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443"))
            {
                ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
                    Console.WriteLine("Message received" + e.Data);

                ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);

                ws.Connect();
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it i get the following console output:

```
Fatal|WebSocket.doHandshake|Not a WebSocket handshake response.
```

According to the [binance websocket stream documentation](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md) you need to change your url to e.g.

```
wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/bnbbtc@ticker
```

I recommend that you print the content of the error message (in this case `e.Message`) if possible because it can give you valuable hints to what might be the cause of the error.

Comment: Hi @Marius this is working perfect, thank you so much!!